# Creating type from functions return value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get rid of repetition in my typescript react code and I was wondering if it was possible to create a type from functions known return type?

Something like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState) => ({settings: store.settings})
type Props = ReturnTypeOf<typeof mapStateToProps>
```

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript actually uses exactly this as an example for conditional types [in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

```
type ReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : any;
```

For your example:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState) => ({settings: store.settings})
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!